# Creating dummy variables in R

Tags: r

How do I create indicator variable in R for whether the bee type is queen or worker? I need this in order to fit a multiple linear regression
I have tried to

Answer (score 1):

Please see function [`gl`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/gl.html) to generate factor by specifying the pattern and the levels. For example:

```
gl(2, 8, labels = c("Bee", "Worker"))
```

creates factor:

> [1] Bee    Bee    Bee    Bee    Bee    Bee    Bee    Bee    Worker Worker Worker Worker Worker Worker Worker Worker
>
> Levels: Bee Worker